# Eclipse plugin: Getting offset of a line

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am new to plugin development and I am writing/ extending a Eclipse plugin. I have initially text file which contains the reults of a code review with the following data.

```
**line_from=70=**     **line_to=80=**     **date=2012/11/20 10:32:54=**     **reviewer=ccc=**     **responsible=xx=**    **revision_nr=1.40=**     **offset=1458=**     **length=344=**
```

Based on some condition, I say that  line number 70 to 80 is same as 100 to 110. Now I want to add a Marker and highlight the lines from 100-110, but I dont have the offset for this location. Can somebody tell me how to get the offset from the line numbers.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think it's too late to answer you, but
maybe I can help anyone else with the same problem.

To solve this, you can use the [IDocument Interface](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/text/IDocument.html).

```
IDocument document = (IDocument) MyPlugin.getEditor().getDocumentProvider().getDocument(MyPlugin.getEditor().getEditorInput());
```

So the document will load the file that was opened in the editor.
You just need to use the getLineOffset() method, that returns the offset of the line.